# AWS EC2 Lifecycle hook: transition after first reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

Somehow I cannot find an answer to seemingly simple question. The setup: auto-scaling group, user data script and CodeDeploy deployment group attached to the ASG. User data script installs packages, makes kernel configuration changes and then reboots the instance. I want to transition instance to LAUNCHED state and trigger code deployment *only* after the first reboot. What is the easiest way to accomplish that?

Comment: Create custom AMI with all software and changes that you have. This will not require any reboots.

Comment: A User Data script will only run on the _first_ boot of the instance. You can put a script in `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/` and it will run on _every_ boot. You might be able to use that to run code after the first reboot.

Comment: @Marcin This would be ideal, but requires heavy lifting in the context of the project and not an option in the near term.

Answer (score 0):

- systemd system service in the ami

  - execstart the shell script below, which will disable this service
  - https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html
  - https://superuser.com/questions/853717/what-is-the-difference-between-systemds-user-and-system-services
- shell script does the following

  - executes aws autoscaling complete-lifecycle-action
  - disables the systemd service above, which called the script
  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/tutorial-lifecycle-hook-instance-metadata.html
- user-data script sudo systemctl enable the service (not start, not --now)